# $f:\mathbb{R}^{+}\to\mathbb{R}^{+}$ is uniformly continuous. Does $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x+\frac{1}{x})}{f(x)}=1$ hold?

Tags: calculus, limits

If $f$ is uniformly continuous,it's easy to show $f(x+\frac{1}{x})-f(x)=o(1).$

So we have $$\frac{f(x+\frac{1}{x})}{f(x)}=1+o(\frac{1}{f(x)})$$

So I think $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x+\frac{1}{x})}{f(x)}=1$ won't necessarily hold.But I cannot find a counterexample.Any help will be thanked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difficulty in finding a counterexample](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118910/difficulty-in-finding-a-counterexample)

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2891136/42969 – – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7Bf(x%2B1%2Fx)%7D%7Bf(x)%7D%3D1%24&p=1)

Answer (score 4):

$f(x)=e^{-x^{2}}$ is uniformly continuous because $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ and $f$ is continuous. In this case you can see that the limit is $e^{-2}$.

Comment: nice. to show uniform continuity, one can note that there is a (uniform) upper bound on its derivative

Comment: @mathworker21 Any continuous function on $\mathbb R_{+}$ which has a finite limit at $\infty$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: erm, yea, good point.

Answer (score 2):

Uniform continuity is about absolute differences, while your fraction cares about relative differences. So if we get a function that gets close enough to $0$ fast enough, we can make the function have big relative difference for $x$ values close together, while not having too large absolute difference (which would break uniform continuity).

With that in mind, $e$ raised to something going to $-\infty$ is a good place to start looking for counterexamples. Which is how you might find something like $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: @mathworker21 My first paragraph isn't a proof of anything. It's how I would think when I start looking for examples.

Comment: I think it is a proof in light of the fact that Kavi Rama Murthy reminded me about, i.e. that any continuous function on $\mathbb{R}_+$ converging to $0$ is uniformly continuous.